# PostgreSQL Timestampz BIRT Params

Tags: postgresql, parameters, birt, timestamp-with-timezone

I am having an issue with adding a timestamp with timezone, aka timestampz, as a parameter in BIRT for querying postgreSQL.

With no param in BIRT the following works fine:

```
WHERE start_date = '2016-02-02 03:26:30.000Z'
```

Now with a param in BIRT, I can't get any combination of a DateTime to work:

```
WHERE start_date = ?
```

Next I make the param which fails as DateTime data type and as string data type:

[image]

In the param editor, I've also tried the following in default value expression:

```
BirtDateTime.now()
```

and

```
new Date().toISOString().replace("T"," ")
```

I always get an error saying:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone = character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I even tried casting like so:

```
WHERE start_date = ?::timestampz
```

BIRT just tells me the syntax is not supported, which means it is just not supported on a parameter.

On another note, how can you debug BIRT queries? I would like to see what the startDate param is right before it is added to the query.

In the mean time I'm going to have to take the "hacky" route. :(

```
WHERE extract(year from start_date) = ?
AND extract(month from start_date) = ?
AND extract(day from start_date) = ?
```

----- **EDIT** -----
Dang! 8 months later and no response. Still haven't figured this out. Just been using the hacky route till this day. I guess just not enough people use BIRT and Postgres :(

Comment: Do you try start_date::TIMESTAMP = '2016-03-24 22:54:03'

Comment: Just tried, did nothing. BIRT did not even recognize the param.

Answer (score 0):

With BIRT 4.6.0, PostgreSQL 9.1.7 and PostgreSQL JDBC driver 9.2.1002, I had success with the parameter having "Data Type" equal to "String" in the "Edit Parameter" dialog for the Data Set, and an SQL query clause like this:

```
WHERE some_field >= TO_DATE(?, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

The string parameter has to be specified in the provided format.

This seems to still be a bit hacky, but not as ugly.

#### Report Parameters

Although the question didn't ask about this type of parameter, I noticed that somehow the above works with them, although I don't understand why.

When I made a Report Parameter of type "Date" and set the data source for a chart to that data set and passed through the Report Parameter as `params["some_param"].value`, it somehow ended up working.  I don't understand why, as `params["some_param"]` is apparently of type `java.sql.Date` (according to an error message I received when playing with this) and it doesn't seem to stringify in "YYYYMMDD" format.

It also worked when I changed to `TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.